# Unable to open database file (gpkg) when creating layers in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, linux

I have some PyQGIS code to create multiple layers in a QGIS project using a `for` loop. This code previously worked for me on Windows, but now I am on Linux and run into the following problem:

```
ERROR 4: sqlite3_open(/path/to/data_source.gpkg) failed: unable to open database file
ERROR 1: unable to open database file
[...]
More than 1000 errors or warnings have been reported. No more will be reported from now.
Critical: Could not create AF_NETLINK socket (Too many open files)
[...]
(qgis:27944): GLib-ERROR **: 00:05:45.770: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files
QGIS died on signal 5ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No thread selected
No stack.
gdb returned 256
Aborted
```

I have (re)created the data source geopackage file on this system without problems, so QGIS is evidently able create and read the `.gpkg` file. Is there any problem in the following code that explains this behavior? Or ideas for what might be wrong with my system/environment/QGIS installation?

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *

root = project.layerTreeRoot()
myPatternsGroup = root.findGroup('My Patterns')
template_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Example layer')[0]

with open('/path/to/patterns.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    for pattern in lines:
        clone = template_layer.clone()
        clone.setName(pattern)
        clone.setSubsetString(f""""field_name" LIKE '%{pattern}%'""")
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(clone, False)
        newLayer = myPatternsGroup.addLayer(clone)
        newLayer.setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

Comment: First thing to check is does `/path/to/data_source.gpkg` actually exist? and then do you have read, write and execute permissions for that directory `/path/to/`?

Comment: Yes, the package path is correct and permissions to the project folder are also set.

Comment: It would seem that each iteration of the for-loop opens the source data file without closing the file descriptor, based on the `Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files` message. But if that is so, why is it opening an already opened file in the first place?

Comment: The GeoTools team is always happy to accept patches providing that everything still works on 8 & 11